# How to call api in ionic using post request and by passing 2 parameters?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I am learning to call api in ionic for sign in purpose. and I  don't know the proper way to call it.

I have tried to call it but it did not success!

**signin.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http'

@Component({
  selector: 'page-sign-in',
  templateUrl: 'sign-in.html',
})
export class SignInPage {

  private signinUrl:"*someurl*";

  email="";
  password="";

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,
  private http:HTTP) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad SignInPage');
  }

  signinClick(){
    this.callSignInApi(this.email,this.password);
  }

  callSignInApi(email:string,password:string){
    console.log('api email',email);
    console.log('api pass',password);

    let urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    urlSearchParams.append('username', email);
    urlSearchParams.append('password', password);

    this.http.post(this.signinUrl,urlSearchParams.toString(),{})
    .then(data => {

      console.log("data status",data.status);
      console.log("data data",data.data); // data received by server
      console.log("data headers",data.headers);

    })
    .catch(error => {

      console.error("catching error",error);
      console.log("error status",error.status);
      console.log("error error",error.error); // error message as string
      console.log("error headers",error.headers);

    });
  }

}
```

Everytime when I click on the button to call the api, It gives me error (but, error is also null). Even I don't know what the error is.
Can anyone guide me how to call api in proper way, and how to pass the parameters in proper way.

Comment: are you using http from `import { Http } from '@angular/http';`

Comment: It is always worth taking a look in the network tab of your developer tools to see the actual request being made. I suspect that `urlSearchParams.toString()` is not doing what you need.

Comment: you can solve using different way but standard way you need to create service for http request handling

Answer (score 1):

You can use Http from @angular/http and make a proper api call.

First add to app.module.ts:

`import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
  imports: [
    ..,
    HttpModule,`

add your page:

inject http: `constructor(public http: Http,.....`

api call:

`this.http.post(this.signinUrl,urlSearchParams.toString(), 
     {}).subscribe(
        data=>{
        ......
       },error=>{
        .....
       });`

Comment: Same url I am using in my another android app. And it is working fine there.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
let urlSearchParams  = {
      'username': email,
      'password': password
  };

this.http.post(this.signinUrl,urlSearchParams,{})
    .then(data => {
         // data received by server
     })
     .catch(error => {
         // error message as string
     });
```

hope this will work!, 
if not try using headers like

```
this.http.post(this.signinUrl,urlSearchParams,{'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
.then(data => {
  // data received by server
})
.catch(error => {
  // error message as string
});
```

Comment: Still getting same results! getting error. (but the object of error is also null).

Answer (score 1):

Try to convert parameter object to URI and then pass like below my working example

```
this.http.post(this.signinUrl,this.formdata(urlSearchParams),{'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
.then(data => {
 // data received by server
})
.catch(error => {
// error message as string
});



/** Convert Object to parameter to send in http request (For not sending json object) */
 formData(myFormData) {
   return Object.keys(myFormData).map(function (key) {
     return encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(myFormData[key]);
 }).join('&');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Import from Angular's HTTP package.

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
```

and remove toString() in case of HTTP POST request:

```
this.http.post(this.signinUrl,urlSearchParams).subscribe(
    data=>{
    ......
   },error=>{
    .....
   });
```

Comment: I've replaced import statement. and chaged code as you told, but now i am getting runtime error  that `StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[SignInPage->Http]: NullInjectorError: No provider for Http!`

Comment: You might not be having HttpModule in your AppModule ts file. Use import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http'; and add in imports section.

Comment: After adding this, I am getting error status 404 when I click sign in button to call api

Comment: U should parse object into string `JSON.stringify(urlSearchParams);` in post method

Comment: @Sanoj_V using JSON.stringify(urlSearchParams); did not work